# argument of type "unsigned int *" is incompatible with parameter of type "size_t *"

Tags: c++, cuda

I have this code in cuda with c++:

```
// Variables
float        *query_dev;
float        *ref_dev;
float        *dist_dev;
int          *ind_dev;
cudaArray    *ref_array;
cudaError_t  result;
size_t       query_pitch;
size_t       query_pitch_in_bytes;
size_t       ref_pitch;
size_t       ref_pitch_in_bytes;
size_t       ind_pitch;
size_t       ind_pitch_in_bytes;
size_t       max_nb_query_traited;
size_t       actual_nb_query_width;
unsigned int memory_total;
unsigned int memory_free;

// Check if we can use texture memory for reference points
unsigned int use_texture = ( ref_width*size_of_float<=MAX_TEXTURE_WIDTH_IN_BYTES && height*size_of_float<=MAX_TEXTURE_HEIGHT_IN_BYTES );

// CUDA Initialisation
cuInit(0);

// Check free memory using driver API ; only (MAX_PART_OF_FREE_MEMORY_USED*100)% of   memory will be used

CUcontext cuContext;
CUdevice  cuDevice=0;
cuCtxCreate(&cuContext, 0, cuDevice);
cuMemGetInfo(&memory_free, &memory_total);
```

I got an error for compiling at the line: cuMemGetInfo(&memory_free, &memory_total);

The errors are:

```
app.cu(311): error: argument of type "unsigned int *" is incompatible with parameter of type "size_t *"

app.cu(311): error: argument of type "unsigned int *" is incompatible with parameter of type "size_t
```

311 is the line of: `cuMemGetInfo(&memory_free, &memory_total);`

I have no clue what is this error, do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the following lines:

```
unsigned int memory_total;
unsigned int memory_free;
```

to:

```
size_t memory_total;
size_t memory_free;
```

You're probably trying an old code that was initially built before CUDA 3.0.

[Source](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=64337)

Answer (score 5):

The error says that `size_t` and `unsigned int` are different types so you can't pass a pointer to one to a function that expects the other.

Either change the types of `memory_free` and `memory_total` to `size_t` or use temporary `size_t` variables and then copy the value into `memory_free` and `memory_total`

P.S. You posted way too much source code, please try to minimize your examples.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you define both

```
unsigned int memory_total;
unsigned int memory_free;
```

as

```
size_t memory_total;
size_t memory_free;
```